# How to get the direct link from a twitter short link

Tags: yahoo-pipes

twitter rss feed links comes short (like http://t.co/rwkYrSPD)

I want to get the direct link with using yahoo pipes

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously you can simply go to the page. for example, http://t.co/rwkYrSPD becomes http://trailers.apple.com/trailers/focus_features/paranorman/

Answer (score 0):

Does Yahoo Pipes have the ability to execute a `HEAD` request against a URL? If you run a `HEAD` against that url (`curl -I 'http://t.co/rwkYrSPD')` you'll get back an `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` response with the actual URL as the `Location` header.

Comment: looks like t.co urls direct to tinyurl, so you'd have to run down the redirect chain until you get a status code % 200 < 100

Comment: @ColinDunklau: This particular t.co URL is redirecting to tinyurl. Others aren't going to do that. But yes, if you want the "true" URL you need to keep running `HEAD` until you stop getting 301 redirects.

Answer (score 0):

I realise it's quite a bit later, now, but check out [the source of this Pipe](http://t.co/rwkYrSPD), which uses the [LongURL API](http://longurl.org/api) (e.g., http://api.longurl.org/v2/expand?url=http://t.co/rwkYrSPD) together with YQL.